# jquery mobile ui-icon not appearing sometimes?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a strange issue with jQuery mobile. I am using the latest version (1.1.1), though I also had this issue with 1.1.0 .

The issue being that my icons sometimes do not appear, as in, the image itself does not appear. I test this in chrome. I am not able to reproduce it on purpose, it is a problem which seems to occur randomly. When it does occur, it looks like the top header in the image below. However, when I open the element inspector in chrome and uncheck/check the background (or indeed any) property, the icon magically appears. Does anyone have any clue what is going on?

An image to illustrate the problem: 
[image: top without icon and bottom with icon]

Edit: to clarify, my associate has had the problem as well. This happened in chrome, but on a different computer, so I doubt any nasty plug-in or so is playing evil here.

Edit2: a couple of things I have tried to resolve this problem.

- preloading through javascript: implementing a line of code to make sure the background is downloaded.
- statically adding a  to the page to see if the controls are downloaded.

The strange thing is that nearly everything is drawn, apart from the background-image. This occurs for **all** the icons by the way, so the ones in listviews etc as well. Navigating through pages or reloading does not matter.

Comment: Does it only happen in chrome? I've had some issues with how chrome handles javascript similar to this before

Comment: As far as I know, yes. But considering this will be a webapp, it will be used in mobile safari and thus webkit... I think you see what's niggling me here ;-)

Comment: Hmmm, this is odd. It could be many things, it sounds to me like its not drawing the control correctly on load, or at least it's not getting the icon. A work around to check this would be to use javascript/jQuery to try and set the icon on page.ready and see if you still have the problem. If so, it seems like an access issue but not sure why it would be random unless access depends on who the user it. If not, then it indeed is an issue with drawing.

Comment: By random I mean that I might have it right now, but if I do the chrome inspector uncheck/check routine, I might not have it for another couple of days. Seems like an issue with the drawing indeed...

Comment: @user1278674, see my answer that would help you.

Comment: I have that behavior too. Only in chrome, other browsers are OK. I'm using CDN. Second tab in same chrome window works ok. Reload with ctrl+f5 fixes the issue. I think it's related to css caching.

Answer (score 1):

actually your app is not able to locate the jQM's CSS so I would recommend to use the CDN's for getting your css.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried the cdn and local versions, but sadly i had the problem with both of them...

Comment: which part exactly? there's quite a bit of code involved in this project (2000 lines of JS, 250 lines of css, ~100 lines of html)

Comment: Sorry it took so long, I'm in europe so we go to bed a little early compared to the US ;-). Anyway, I put a fiddle online with my html code: http://jsfiddle.net/2M8fs/ . I did change the url of the css to the cdn in this version, but the results are the same (apart from the disc being different from my image, but considering the white icon is a separate div that shouldn't be an issue I think)

Comment: You need to make sure to use the CSS URL on ALL pages of your site/app because JQM caches the CSS, so it may be pulling an incorrect link from a diff page. I would check the CSS URL on all pages.

Comment: I only use 1 html page, the actual page switching happens via javascript. So the head section is, indeed, the same for all the pages.